# How to get rid of Pocket in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, pocket

Unfortunately, Pocket is now "integrated" with Firefox, which means that it is not possible disable it in the Add-ons menu.

I find the icon in the address bar especially annoying, as it is essentially just an always-visible advertisement for that webservice.

How can I now get rid of Pocket in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to get ride of the pocket or disable is as follows

1. visit about:config
2. in Firefox Accept the Warning
3. In search bar of that page (after all config value comes), search for Pocket.
4. You can see **extensions.pocket.enabled**
5. You can double click on it to toggle(it will be set to false)

Comment: Thanks, that's much better than my solution!

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the "Pocket" icon is possible as follows:

- Right-click on the "Pocket" icon
- Click "Remove from Address Bar"

However, fully disabling that extension is hard. It is still available when you click on the ellipses "..." in the address bar, but at least the annoying icon is no longer wastes space.